# Terraform - Variable defined in "*.auto.tfvars" file, but still cannot be discovered

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have the following directory Structure:

```
.
├── ./first_terraform.tf
├── ./modules
│   └── ./modules/ssh_keys
│       ├── ./modules/ssh_keys/main.tf
│       ├── ./modules/ssh_keys/outputs.tf
│       └── ./modules/ssh_keys/variables.tf
├── ./terraform.auto.tfvars
├── ./variables.tf
```

I am trying to pass a variable `ssh_key` to my child module defined as `main.tf` inside `./modules/ssh_keys/main.tf`

```
resource "aws_key_pair" "id_rsa_ec2" {
  key_name   = "id_rsa_ec2"
  public_key = file(var.ssh_key)
}
```

I also have this variable defined both at `root` and `child` level `variables.tf` file. For the value, I have set it in `terraform.auto.tfvars` as below

```
# SSH Key
ssh_key = "~/.ssh/haha_key.pub"
```

I also have a variable defined in root level and child level `variables.tf` file:

```
variable "ssh_key" {
  type        = string
  description = "ssh key for EC2 login and checks"
}
```

My root terraform configuration has this module declared as:

```
module "ssh_keys" {
  source = "./modules/ssh_keys"
}
```

I first did a `terraform init -upgrade` on my root level. Then ran `terraform refresh` and got hit by the following error.

```
Error: Missing required argument

  on first_terraform.tf line 69, in module "ssh_keys":
  69: module "ssh_keys" {

The argument "ssh_key" is required, but no definition was found.
```

Just for reference, line 69 in my root level configuration is where the `module` declaration has been made. I don't know what I have done wrong here. It seems I have all the variables declared, so am I missing some relationship between root/child module variable passing etc.?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I **Think** I know what I did wrong.

Terraform Modules - as per the documentation requires parents to pass on variables as part of invocation. For example:

module "foo" {
source      =  "./modules/foo"
var1        =  value
var2        =  value

}

The above `var1`, `var2` can come from either `auto.tfvars` file, environment variables (recommended) or even command line `-var-file` calls. In fact, this is what Terraform calls "Calling a Child Module" [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/syntax.html#calling-a-child-module)

Once I did that, everything worked like a charm! I hope I did find the correct way of doing things.